# Runnable jar or bat file for executing java Desktop applications

Tags: java, deployment, jar, batch-file, executable-jar

As I know there are two standard ways you can distribute a Java desktop application:

1. Through a runnable jar file
2. Through a bat file which calls a jar file to begin execution

I want to know what is the  best way among these methods and what are the relative advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 1):

The list is missing the best one!

1. ..
2. ..
3. [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> Java Web Start (JWS) is the Oracle Corporation technology used to launch rich client (Swing, AWT, SWT) *desktop applications* directly from a network or internet link. It offers 'one click' installation for platforms that support Java.
>
> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

In case it is not clear, I vote JWS as the 'best' from a user point of view.  The details of the advantages are pretty much expressed in the 2nd paragraph of the description, but also the last sentence of the first.  Not to forget the 1st sentence of the next paragraph..

> By default, an applet-like security sand-box is applied to code launched using JWS.  ..

Answer (score 0):

I think runnable jar would be a good option for desktop application. As I am using it for my desktop application is more comfortable and user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will depend on who are the users of your application.
If the users are non-tech people you better go with a runnable jar because
they are less likely to pass an argument to your program.

In case they are your team members or other tech people, you may give them a .bat
to play around with your app.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, wrappers like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) could be considered.

Answer (score -1):

The open source software always use .bat or .sh file to distribute a java application.I think this way would be a good option.